# react testing library toHaveBeenCalled 0 mocking a simple click prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-testing-library

I try to mock a prop called actionClicked but my test failed, I have a simple component as below

```
const ButtonAction: React.FC = ({ actionClicked }) => {
    const handleClick = (action) => () => actionClicked(action)
  
    return (
          <div
            data-testid="some-action"
            onClick={handleClick('something')}
          >
              <Icon />
          </div>
    )
  }
```

this is my test, button.spec.tsx

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react'
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event'

import React from 'react'

import ButtonAction from './ButtonAction'

test('render ButtonAction', () => {
  const actionClicked = jest.fn()

  render(<ButtonAction actionClicked={actionClicked} />)

  userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId('some-action'))
  expect(actionClicked).toHaveBeenCalled() //failed here
})
```

I'm not sure why `actionClicked` is not been called.

```
Expected number of calls: >= 1
Received number of calls:    0
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behaviour occurs because `userEvent.click` returns a promise.

First you should turn your test to `async` and then `await userEvent.click`:

```js
test("render ButtonAction", async () => {
  const actionClicked = jest.fn();

  render(<ButtonAction actionClicked={actionClicked} />);

  await userEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("some-action"));

  expect(actionClicked).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

Comment: I see. it worked, but why does this worked?
```render(<ButtonAction actionClicked={actionClicked} />);
  expect(screen.getByText('some other text if I have any')).toBeInTheDocument()```
without the wait? does await apply to click only?

Comment: In your example, when you render the component it's assumed that its on the screen (you just redenred it), and because of that `toBeInTheDocument` will be true. About the click, the user event could take some milliseconds to take effect and that's why the `await` in this case is important. I don't know if I made myself clear, but feel free to ask anything.